# Supplementary problems on lattices From Schaum Series Boolean Algebra $2$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, logic, boolean-algebra, algebraic-logic

Find whether the following partially ordered sets are lattices, whether they have a zero and unit elements and whether they are complemented lattices:

**(b)** The set of all ordered pairs $(a,b)$ of real numbers, partially ordered by $\leq$, where: $(a_{1},b_{1})$$\leq$$(a_{2},b_{2}$) iff $(a_{1} < a_{2})$ or $(a_{1} = a_{2}$ & $b_{1}$$\leq$$\ b_{2}$).

I feel it is a lattice because every two elements has an infimium which is (min $(a_{1},a_{2})$, min $(b_{1},b_{2})$) and every two elements has a supremium which is (max $(a_{1},a_{2})$, max $(b_{1},b_{2}).$)

Also I feel that the zero element is (0,0)  and  unit element is (1,1).I do not think it is a complemented lattice but I do not know how to justify this.

Could anyone help me please?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order relation you describe for pairs of real numbers is usually called the lexicographic order.  The resulting partially ordered set is also a lattice, but the supremum of $(1,2)$, $(2,1)$ is $(2,1)$, not $(2,2)$ and their infimum is $(1,2)$, not $(1,1)$.

In fact, this partial order is a total order: every two pairs of real numbers are comparable according to your definition of $\leq$.  (Contrast this to the case of the powerset of a set, in which $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ are not comparable: it's neither $\{1,2\} \subseteq \{2,3\}$ nor $\{2,3\} \subseteq \{1,2\}$.)

Consequently the supremum of two pairs is the larger of the two and the infimum is the smaller of the two.  Of course, if the two pairs are identical, they are both the supremum and the infimum.

It's easy to see how to extend the lexicographic ordering to tuples of real numbers.

Comment: why is its supremum and infimum looks like this?

Comment: @MathLover the supremum of $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ is $(2,1)$ because $(1,2) \leq (2,1)$ (and for the same reason, the infimum is $(1,2)$).

Comment: Also, there is no $0$ element (that is, a smallest element), and no $1$ (greatest element) either; thus it is not a bounded lattice and so, it is not complemented.

Comment: And it's worth noting that "bounded" does not imply "finite."  For instance, $2^\mathbb{N}$ under set inclusion is bounded, because $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are bottom and top, respectively; however, it is obviously (uncountably) infinite.  In fact, $2^\mathbb{N}$ under set inclusion is an infinite Boolean algebra.

Comment: @MathLover As an addendum to what amrsa noted, whenever in a lattice $a \leq b$ holds, then the supremum is $b$ and the infimum is $a$.  When the partial order turns out to be total, as in this case, one of $a \leq b$ and $b \leq a$ is always true; hence supremum and infimum are either $a$ or $b$.

Comment: @amrsa  Is there is a relation between a bounded lattice and a complemented lattice? and what is the definition of a bounded lattice?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi   Do u mean by $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ the power set?

Comment: @MathLover Yes, I mean the power set of $\mathbb{N}$.  A bounded lattice is simply a lattice that has a greatest element (top) and a least element (bottom).  The definition of complement depends on their existence.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi  Could u please clarify this "The definition of complement depends on their existence?"

Comment: A complement of $a$ is defined as an element $b$ such that the supremum of $a$ and $b$ is top and the infimum of $a$ and $b$ is bottom.  If the lattice has no top or bottom, there cannot be complements in it.